# How can I load my own dataset for person?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, spyder

How can I load a dataset for person reidentification. In my dataset there are two folders train and test.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could provide comments, but I cannot yet. Therefore, I will "answer" your question to the best of my ability.

First, you should provide a general format or example content of the dataset. This would help me provide a less nebulous answer.

Second, from the nature of your question I am assuming that you are fairly new to python in general. Forgive me if I'm wrong in my assumption. With that assumption, depending on what kind of data you are trying to load (i.e. text, numbers, or a mixture of text and numbers) there are various ways to load the data. Some of the methods are easier than others. If you are strictly loading numbers, I suggest using `numpy.loadtxt(<file name>).` If you are using text, you could use the Pandas package, or if it's in a CSV file you could use the built-in (into Python that is) CSV package. Alternatively, if it's in a format that Tensorflow can read, you could use the provided load data functions.

Once you have loaded your data you will need to separate the data into the input and output values. Considering that Tensorflow models accept either lists or numpy arrays, you should be able to use these in your training and testing steps.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout modules csv (import csv) or load your dataset via open(filename, „r“) or so. It might be easiest if you provide more context/info.